# Calling mssql stored procedure using pdo sqlsrv drivers with multi queries inside procedure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sqlsrv, mssql-jdbc

I'm facing the problem while calling stored procedure by using sqlsrv drivers in laravel. Inside procedure there are multiple queries with combination of select and insert. I unable to share code here as its privacy issue.

So can any one please share the code which can work with laravel to call mssql procedure with multiple result row set.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Without your code it's difficult to help you, may be this question would help you:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695287/how-to-fetch-multiple-result-set-from-a-mysql-stored-procedure-in-laravel)

Comment: If you are using action stored procedures then you have to pass the action for select,insert or update etc. you can do it in this way `$result = DB::select('CALL Procedure_Name(?,?,?)', array($action,$val1, $val2)); return $result;` these `?,?,?` are your procedures parameters, and you have to do all this in laravel model

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz Thanks for reply sorry but here its privacy issue so cant share the code. i checked your link we already done this thing for mysql but now we are looking for mssql.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir already tried this one but no luck its not works for multi result row set.

Comment: What do you mean for multi rows ? are you passing arrays ?

Comment: multi rows result set means inside procedure there are multiple queries like select and insert so it returns multiple result row set of each query.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server supports stored procedures that can return more than one result set. With PHP and PDO you can retrieve these result sets with [PDOStatement::nextRowset()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) method. It is important to note, that if you have output parameters in your stored procedure, you need to fetch all result sets to get the output values.

If Laravel do not support `nextRowset()`, you may try to get the underlying `PDO` instance using the `getPdo()` method on a connection instance and use this instance for statement execution:

```
<?php

...
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
try {
    $sql = "{CALL usp_TestProcedure(?)}";
    $param = 'ParamValue';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $param);
    $stmt->execute();
    do {
       while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          print_r($row, true); 
          echo '<br>';
       }
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());  
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error executing query" );
}
...

?>
```