# how to get results of a store procedure with laravel in the way that all of results can be shown

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, stored-procedures

I have a store procedure in mysql and when I run it with phpmyadmin tools, results are like this
[my myql procedure result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Ogk.png)

that all of semi-tables (I mean result sets) are correct. but with laravel code including this

```
$dataSet = DB::select('CALL MY_PROC(?,?);', array($param1, $param2));
return \Response::json([
    'dt1' => $dataSet,
], 200);
```

I get this result

```
{"dt1":[
      {"operation4":7185,"operation5":18167}
]}
```

that means it gives me just one of result sets. how can I get all of result set with laravel?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+select+multiple+result+sets+from+stored+procedure - I don't Laravel but I would imagine someone has tried to do this before, and succeeded.

Comment: I googled it before! call and exec are not answer

Comment: Well, they're potentially involved, but maybe not the whole solution. Your vague description makes it hard to know precisely what you've tried or what the problems were, though. What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695287/how-to-fetch-multiple-result-set-from-a-mysql-stored-procedure-in-laravel/28043584#28043584 ?

Comment: Or what about this ready-made package? https://github.com/rodion-arr/laravel-mysql-stored-procedures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on @ADyson help, I find out "Laravel's DB facade does not support calling stored procedures that returns multiple data sets in result out of the box" and this github repository is working for me
https://github.com/rodion-arr/laravel-mysql-stored-procedures